# Removing the custom_image_header from wp_head

Tags: plugins, theme-development, functions, themes

I am looking to remove the custom_image_header from the wp_head. I would like to use this in a more manual way throughout my theme.  I understand the general approach for this is to include CSS in the head but I would like to keep all of the CSS for the theme outside of the head.

Any ideas?

Thank in advance,

JN

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove this by using 
`remove_action('wp_head', 'header_uri');`

Where `header_uri` is displayed in the above function you must use the same function name you have used to initialize the function in `add_custom_image_header()` within your functions.php file.

.  example: `add_custom_image_header('header_uri', 'admin_header_style');`